# How can I add more text into a plot using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have this graph that I made using this code:

```
df3 <- data.frame(outcome=c("Any complication", "Cardiac complication",
                            "Vascular Complication","Vascular complication",
                            "Respiratory complication", "Infectious complication",
                            "Neurological complication"),
                 index=1:7,
                 effect=c(-.4, -.25, -.1, .1, .15, .2, .3),
                 lower=c(-.43, -.29, -.17, -.02, .04, .17, .27),
                 upper=c(-.37, -.21, -.03, .22, .24, .23, .33))

plot2 <- ggplot(data=df3, aes(y=index, x=effect, xmin=lower, xmax=upper))+
  geom_point(shape="diamond", colour="royalblue4", size=5) + 
  geom_errorbarh(height=.2, colour="royalblue4") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:nrow(df3), labels=df3$outcome) +
  labs(title="Adjusted Relative Risk for Complications", x="Relative Risk", y = "Type of complication") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, color='gray', linetype='dashed', alpha=.5) +
  theme_minimal()+
  plots_theme
```

[image: My graph]

But I would like to add the RR, the 95% confidence interval and some other things there, as shown here:

[image: The graph I want :)]

I could really use some help! Quite new in R here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier, I would borrow one of several R packages which can make forest plots. As a quick start, I use `forestplot` package here as an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forestplot)
df3 %>%
  mutate(ci = paste0(" (", lower, ",  ", upper, ")")) %>%
  arrange(-index) %>%
  forestplot::forestplot(
    labeltext = c(outcome, effect, ci),
    mean = effect, 
    low = lower,
    upper = upper,
    size = 0.1,
    graph.pos = 2,
    vertices = TRUE,
    xlab = "Relative Risk", 
    title="Adjusted Relative Risk for Complications") %>% 
  fp_add_header(
    outcome = c("Outcome"),
    effect = c("Estimate"), 
    ci = "95% (CI)") %>% 
  fp_set_style(box = "royalblue4", line = "royalblue4")
```

[image]

## Edit

Just something different from your question, the `Estimate` values shown in the graph may not be relative risk but regression coefficient. If you would like to present relative risk, you could take an advantage of `meta` package:

```
library(meta)
df3 <- df3 %>% arrange(-index)
forest_df <-metagen(lower = lower, 
              upper = upper, 
              TE = effect,
              data = df3, 
              sm = "RR")

forest(forest_df,
       studlab = paste0(outcome), 
       layout = "JAMA", 
       common = FALSE, 
       hetstat = FALSE, 
       overall = FALSE)
```

Get work done with less code and journal format.

[image]

Comment: OMG I just realized this! How silly hahaha of course RR can't be negative! Thank you so much for your input, highly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here a way with geom_rect, geom_text and annotate.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df3 <- data.frame(outcome=c("Any complication", "Cardiac complication",
                            "Vascular Complication","Vascular complication",
                            "Respiratory complication", "Infectious complication",
                            "Neurological complication"),
                 index=1:7,
                 effect=c(-.4, -.25, -.1, .1, .15, .2, .3),
                 lower=c(-.43, -.29, -.17, -.02, .04, .17, .27),
                 upper=c(-.37, -.21, -.03, .22, .24, .23, .33))

ggplot(data=df3, aes(y=index, x=effect, xmin=lower, xmax=upper))+
  geom_point(shape="diamond", colour="royalblue4", size=5) + 
  geom_errorbarh(height=.2, colour="royalblue4") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:nrow(df3), labels=df3$outcome) +
  labs(title="Adjusted Relative Risk for Complications", x="Relative Risk", y = "Type of complication") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, color='gray', linetype='dashed', alpha=.5) +
  annotate("rect",  xmin=.5, xmax= 1, ymin=0, ymax= 8, fill = "white")+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(effect, "(", lower, ",", upper,")")) ,
            x= 0.5, hjust="left") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 1.0))+
  annotate("text", label = "Estimate  - 95% CI", x = 0.5, hjust="left", y= 8)+
  theme_minimal() + theme()
```

[image]

Comment: This was super helpful to understand annotate and geom_text! Thank you so much!!!!